# WMS not loading in QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm using QGIS 2.6.1 Brighton, trying to load the following WMS layer:
http://services.nconemap.com/arcgis/services/Imagery/Orthoimagery_Latest/ImageServer/WMSServer

I can successfully load the WMS in ArcGIS, and have spoken with the service providers, who have recently upgraded the service to work with the latest standard for WMS. I was advised to make sure the DPI mode is turned off, but it seems to have no effect.

When I try to add a new WMS layer, the layer appears in the browser window, when I expand the layer, it processes for a few seconds and then stops. Nothing displays in the expanded view and the layer will not add.

What do I need to do to get this layer to load? Does anyone else have success loading this layer in QGIS 2.6.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in 2.8. Try the following options in the connection:

[image]

Comment: However, there is something odd. Server is advertising `http://services.nconemap.com/arcgis/services/Imagery/Orthoimagery_Latest/ImageServer/WMSServer`as GetMap URL which seems to be identical as the GetCapabilities URL. There should be no reason to check the "ignore" boxes. Perhaps some temporary failure in the service, or something like a bug in QGIS?

Comment: Thanks for the help! I still cannot successfully load the WMS by creating a WMS "New Connection" in the browser window, but when I use the "Add WMS/WMTS Layer" option in the drop-down under the "Layer" menu, the layer loads. Was reminded of this option by looking at your uploaded image.

Answer (score 3):

Works also with QGIS 2.6.1 if the 
"Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities"-option is checked:
[image]