# Digimap OpenStream timeout

Tags: qgis, wms, connection

I am having trouble with an WMS layer that calls the Ordnance Survey/Digimap OpenStream data, but however I call the layer it times out without ever displaying a map.

I have registered with Digimap and have my own API key. I have successfully created a WMS connection that allows me to call an OpenStream layer, but once I have clicked 'Add' to place the layer in the map, nothing appears until I receive a notice saying 'connection timed out'. This problem occurs whatever parameters I set for the OpenStream entry (username and password, CRS options, tile size... ). I can successfully create and load other WMS connections and add a layer, such as the following: http://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service

I am not seeing firewall reports that suggest that my firewall is blocking incoming or outgoing connections, and QGIS is an allowed application (allow TCP/IP and UDP in and out).

System is QGIS 2.14.15 ltr on Windows 7 Ult 64 bit.

Is this a temporary fault with Edina (could others test, please), or have I got something basic wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, and based on another response on StackExchange ([https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137369/wms-not-loading-in-qgis-2-6-1-brighton](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137369/wms-not-loading-in-qgis-2-6-1-brighton), #3, Thomas B,) I have ticked the "Ignore GetMap/GetTile URI reported in capabilities" option for the connection and it works, mostly. I still have a blank screen on loading (map fully zoomed out by default), but if I zoom in the map appears (I tried this before, but nothing ever appeared). I still have random warnings about the server timing out and incomplete data, but this must be between mt connection and OS/Edina/Digimap, not a QGIS issue.